# CXF & Spring - Autowired on jax-rs service bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

**Introduction**

I have start a new basic application with CXF Frameworks and Spring, and connect all together with a simple experimental controller.

The experimental controller works if I'm not using injection (on attribute) and can't even run if I set the injection on the constructor (no default constructor).

**Question**

How does Spring and CXF work together, and how I am supposed to success the injection (on the constructor if possible) ?

**Sources**

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
          http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>

  <jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <bean class="tp.rest.ExperimentalController"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
      <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
  </jaxrs:server>

  <!-- enable CXF JMX -->
  <bean id="org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager"
        class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
    <property name="enabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf"/>
    <property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true"/>
    <property name="createMBServerConnectorFactory" value="false"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <display-name>Experimental</display-name>
  <description>Experimental</description>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**ExperimentalController**

```
@Path("/expe")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public class ExperimentalController {

    @Autowired
    private Test test;

    @GET
    public Test test() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@Component
@XmlRootElement
public class Test {
    private String value = "test";

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

*If needed, I can also provided the pom.xml.*